# Material UI Sticky AppBar below the other AppBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to know how to make an AppBar sticky below the other AppBar?
when I set position="sticky", it will overlay the top AppBar, maybe I need to set something like top: "myTopAppBar px"? but how?

[demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-swartz-l5fom)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your second `AppBar` inside the first one. Move the closing tag `</AppBar>` of your first `AppBar` under the closing tag of the second `AppBar`.
[image]

Comment: Is there another way... a better way that that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this CSS:

```
.MuiPaper-elevation4 {
  top: 64px;
}
.MuiAppBar-positionSticky {
  position: fixed;
}
```

forked [codebox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-http-qjobk)

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to make two AppBars one below another instead of putting lower one inside of the upper one or writing CSS.

After moving the lower AppBar out of the upper AppBar, we can make its position "fixed" and add style={{ marginTop: "64px" }} to make it always show below the upper one.

```
<AppBar
    component="div"
    color="primary"
    position="fixed"
    indicatorColor="primary"
    style={{ marginTop: "64px" }}
>
```

Btw, if we set marginTop of the AppBar, it will cover the main text, which can be solve by setting

```
<main style={{ marginTop: "40px" }}>
```

[Your Edited CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-shadow-kwtzm3?file=/src/App.js:2811-2847)
Hope this will help.